# How show Navigation bar of button home, menu and back?

Tags: android

With some divice android has got 3 button: Home,Menu and Back at the bottom.
But some divice android phone hasn't got 3 button:  Home,Menu and Back.
How show 3 button Home,Menu and Back at bottom of screen as Action Bar?
AS:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an action bar. This is the navigation bar, available on some phones. Specifically, it will be on phones that are running Android 4.0 or higher and do not have off-screen affordances for these keys.

> How show 3 button Home,Menu and Back at bottom of screen

This is handled at the firmware level. The device manufacturer will set up the firmware to display the navigation bar where needed. You cannot add a navigation bar for devices that do not need one via the Android SDK.